# Server hello is not returned without SNI

Tags: ssl, tcp, tls

I've setup a proxy server (squid) with `https_port` enabled. When I send requests to this server using a url like `domain.com` or even using a host alias (i.e. manually written in `/etc/hosts`), there's no problem and everything works fine. The problem appears when sending requests to the server using its IP address. In this case, the request hangs after `Client Hello` phase.

The only difference between these two situations is that the second type of requests does not contain server name indication (SNI) extension but I've seen other examples working without SNI.

What should I do to make the TLS handshake work even for all requests?

Comment: Are you using Squid as a reverse proxy?

Comment: No. Just as a normal forward proxy.

Comment: As a forward proxy, how would Squid know what website you're trying to access if it's not told via SNI?

Comment: My question is about the squid itself.

Answer (score 1):

[SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is a technology specifically designed to allow a server to host multiple sites with different certificates on a single IP address. in order to do that though, the HTTP request must contain a `host` [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Generally when a webserver admin sets up SNI, they select a default host to use when no host header is provided, as would be the case with a request by IP address. the details depend on the webserver in question, but you should be able to find instructions for whatever webserver you are running.

Note that this issue impacts servers configured to use SNI regardless of your proxy implementation. the issue and the fix are not directly related. there are just some sites you can't use by IP.

Comment: You mean I should change some setting in the host OS?
`Note that this issue impacts servers configured to use SNI regardless of your proxy implementation. the issue and the fix are not directly related`

Comment: yes, setting a default SNI host for the webserver allows the server to detemine which site to serve, even if the HTTP request does not specify one. i understand this may not completely solve your issue, as remote site administrators may not have correctly established a default, but that is not really under your control, unless you choose to use a host/domain name instead of an IP. there are lots of technologies like load balances and Geo-located services that don't work best when using IPs anyway, so let the DNS infrastructure solve this issue for you, by using FQDNs to access sites.

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank.